# Elementary row operations versus matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can every elementary row op on a matrix be represented by multiplying that very matrix by an elementary matrix?

Comment: Yes. Every elementary row operation can be performed by left multiplication by an elementary matrix. Just as every elementary column operation can be performed by right multiplication by an elementary matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. I will give you the matrices in each case: Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

1) Multiplying ***row* $i$** of $M$ by a non-zero scalar $c$ corresponds to multiplying $M$ on the left by the matrix $X$ where $X$ is the same as the identity matrix, but the $(i,i)^{th}$ entry replaced by $c$.

2) Interchanging rows $i$ and $j$ of $M$ corresponds to multiplying $M$ on the left by the matrix $X_1$ where $X_1$ is the identity matrix with the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ diagonal entries replaced by $0$ and the $(i,j)^{th}$ and $(j,i)^{th}$ entries replaced by $1$.

3) Adding $c(row \hspace{1mm}j)$ to $row \hspace{1mm} i$ corresponds to multiplying $M$ on the left by the matrix $X_2$ where $X_2$ is the identity matrix with $(i,j)^{th}$ entry replaced by $c$.

Hope this helps. Column operations correspond to multiplying by elementary matrices on the right.

Comment: I hope there are no errors with how I wrote the entries.

Comment: Note also that the elementary matrix corresponding to a given row operation can be obtained by doing that row operation to the identity matrix of the correct size, and likewise for column operations.